# use nodejs to download bing's wallpaper

Tags: node.js

i want to download bing's todays wallpaper by node.js,

first of all,**i can download large pictures from some other sites**,

but i can't download the pic from bing,even though i can see the pic in my browser

the example picture src is : "http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fYosemiteSnow_EN-US7191433727_1920x1200.jpg"

here's my core code

```
var download_file_httpget = function(file_url) {
    var options = {
        host: url.parse(file_url).host,
        port: 80,
        path: url.parse(file_url).pathname,
        headers: {}
    };
    var file_name = '11.jpg';
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(download_path + "\\" + file_name);
    http.get(options,function(res) {
        res.on('data',function(data) {
            file.write(data);
        }).on('end',function() {
            file.end();
            console.log('download success');
        });
    });
};
```

for example,the orginal pic's size is 200k,but it only download 20k,and i doubt that it is because of the 'referer' in the header,when i add the header,the problem fixed in some oher sites,but it still dosen't work for bing

Comment: for example,the orginal pic's size is 200k,but it only download 20k,and i doubt that it is because of the referer in the header,when i add the header,the problem fixed in some oher sites,but it still dosen't work for bing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to

```
path: url.parse(file_url).path,
```

will include the query string and get you the entire file.

The file that gets downloaded is an [HTML text file](http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg), not jpeg.

```
console.log(url.parse(file_url));
```

Shows this:

```
{
    protocol: 'http:',
    slashes: true,
    host: 'www.bing.com',
    hostname: 'www.bing.com',
    href: 'http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fYosemiteSnow_EN-US7191433727_1920x1200.jpg',
    search: '?p=rb%2fYosemiteSnow_EN-US7191433727_1920x1200.jpg',
    query: 'p=rb%2fYosemiteSnow_EN-US7191433727_1920x1200.jpg',
    pathname: '/az/hprichbg',
    path: '/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fYosemiteSnow_EN-US7191433727_1920x1200.jpg'
}
```

Since you are using `pathname`, the url is:

```
http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg
```

so Bing doesn't know which image to return.